# ArrayOutofBounds and NumberFormat Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am getting those two exceptions when using token split method and parse int.
ArrayOutofBounds when I have the printline statement in the code, and the other one when I comment out the printline statement

```
public class MyArtistNodes {

public ArrayList<ArtistNode> myArtistNodes = null;

public MyArtistNodes(String filename) {
       Scanner input;


       try {
           input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
           myArtistNodes = new ArrayList<ArtistNode>();
           while(input != null && input.hasNext()) {

               String line = input.nextLine();
               String[] tokens = line.trim().split("@");
               tokens = line.split(" ");
              // System.out.println(tokens.length+" "+tokens[1]+" -- "+Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()));
               ArtistNode newA = new ArtistNode(tokens[1],Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()));
               myArtistNodes.add(newA);
           }
           input.close();

       } catch (NumberFormatException | FileNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Error:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

     at MyArtistNodes.<init>(MyArtistNodes.java:27)

     at Exam3Step3A.<init>(Exam3Step3A.java:6)

     at Exam3.main(Exam3.java:6)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging or Googling for those errors? Those are usually the 2 most straight forward exceptions to solve.

Comment: Yes I have, nothing really working out

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` means that you're trying to access to the element at index `1` in an array that is not long enough. It means that your array contains only one element (at index `0`). The only array I see in your code is `tokens`, make sure that it contains the `@` as you expect

Comment: the list does not have @, I found online that you have to initialize the token

Comment: If the string doesn't contain the `@` the array will have just one element and you won't be able to access `tokens[1]`. Do you want to create an `ArtistNode` with an empty string or just ignore that case?

Comment: I have to create a list through reading from file, so It should not be an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Error NumberFormat Exception it could be because of this line:

```
       ArtistNode newA = new ArtistNode(tokens[1],Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()));
```

as you can see you're traying to make an Integer from a String (tokens[0]) so, your token[0] must not be a valid number sometimes and that is why you get that excepcion.

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

it could be because you're trying to read the array in a position that does not exist and the problem should be in the same line:

```
   ArtistNode newA = new ArtistNode(tokens[1],Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()));
```

maybe your

```
  String[] tokens = line.trim().split("@");
               tokens = line.split(" ");
```

split didn't work for all cases.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have to read file into the list, and then read it to reverse the order of list to write to another file. The file does contain entries like : 1 Acconci (\n)  2 Batte

Comment: Well you are using  tokens = line.split(" "); so you will split this 1 Acconci (\n) 2  in withe spaces and Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()) will be correct, but are you sure that this file always will be splited with withes? what if you get a line with this: 1Acconci (\n) 2 , see? now your programm will try this Integer.parseInt("1Acconci") and you will get the error

Comment: But the input file is tab delimited already, so that should not be the case

Comment: that is wy i told you, be carefull , why not use a regex? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are in the form of (`String`, `int`), ..., but you parse them in the form of ('int', 'String'), ..., basically this line:

```
ArtistNode newA = new ArtistNode(tokens[1],Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim()));
```

should look like this:

```
ArtistNode newA = new ArtistNode(tokens[0],Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim()));
```

Comment: Example 1 Acconci
2 Budd
3 Carpenter
4 Dill
5 Edwards

Comment: Why are you splitting on `@` if the input doesn't contain that symbol??

Comment: I thought I had to initialize the tokens. I found that online but it does not work

Comment: Well simply put that is not how it works. You initialize the variable by the value of `String.split()`.

Comment: I already tried that and it would give me Array Out of Bounds exception : 1